# Why these closure based private variables in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I am experimenting imitating OOP like behavior in JS. I am trying to have (private) variables: `id` and `name` in function `Person`. To this function I am passing arguments which are used to initialize (private) variables. Then I am returning object having getter and setter for `name` and only a getter for `id`, thus effectively making `id` read-only.

So id can be set only through constructor whereas name can be set and get anytime.

This is the code:

```
     var Person = function (_id,_nm) {
        var id, name;    
                  
        this.id = _id;
        this.name = _nm;

        return {               
            setName: function (nm) {
                name = nm;
            },
            getName: function () {
                return name;
            },
            getId: function () {
                return id;
            },
            print: function () {
                document.writeln("Id: "+id+"<br />Name: "+name);
            }
        }
    }

    var person = new Person(123, "Mahesh");
    person.print();
```

However when `new Person(123,"Mahesh")` executes, I dont understand it is actually setting `id` and `name` or not, since while debugging I can see values set appropriately when hovered over them but Locals panel does not show them initialized:

[image: Debugging]

Or either while in print() is is not referring to the desired `id` and `name` variables:

[image: Debugging]

Whats wrong here?

Comment: why are you working with IE? O.o

Comment: hey hey ok noob here :P what u use? Is IE so bad? Its just that am comfortable with. See it looks clean.

Comment: Yes it's bad (if less than IE10)..I wouldn't get into why it's bad because that is not for a comment here, but I would suggest you to work with Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: You should have a look at [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object) for the difference between properties ("public") and variables ("private")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/y7Xbb/2/)**

The reason is because you are using `public` members for the `Person.prototype`. You don't need to add `this` references to these two. So delete:

```
this.id = _id;
this.name = _nm;
```

and simply use:

```
 var id = _id,
     name = _nm;
```

Now everything will work fine. The whole idea is to use `var`, and not `this`, otherwise a closure will not be created. Now you will not be able to access `name` and `id` directly, instead you will have to use `setName(), getName(), setId(), getId()` etc.

The two members, `id` and `name`, will now become closures as you want them to be.

**Update**

If you used `this.id`, then it wouldn't have been `private` and you could just do `var p = new Person(1, "Mahesha");` and access `p.name` or `p.id` directly. They are supposed to be `private` so this is not what you want.

With the closure pattern, p.name and p.id are undefined and can only be accessed through `p.getName();` and `p.getId();`. Read on how closures work. The idea is that because you are using that `var name`, a closure will be created to remember it's value.

Your `getName` and `setName` are using that closure to access the `name` property. There is no `this.name`, there is a value remembered through a higher - order closure.

Comment: Perfectly pin pointed but not yet able to understand completely:`1.`Where exactly `this.id` and `this.name` goes if not in closure? `2.`Not able to understand what you meant by "The reason is because you are using public members for the Person.prototype."

Comment: No am not able to access them as `p.name` and `p.id` when I used `this.id=_id` and `this.name=_nm`

Comment: yes that worked for me too, what I am saying is that `document.writeln(p.name)` and `document.writeln(p.id)` is not working when `this.id = _id` and `this.name = _nm` is kept as you said in previous comment

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up using locally scoped ("private") variables for `_id` and `_nm` and "public" instance properties (`this.id` and `this.nm`).

In this case you need the former, but you created both and only initialised the latter.

Note that since `id` is read-only you don't really need a separate local variable at all, you can just use the lexically scoped first parameter to the constructor:

```
var Person = function (id, _nm) {
    var name = _nm;

    ...
};
```

Comment: Please call them "properties", not "variables", but you're right

Answer (score 1):

`this.id` and `var id` are not the same. `this.id` is a property of the object. `var id` belongs to the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

**Either use `new` or return a value. Not both.**

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of `Person` using the `new` keyword, but your constructor function is returning another object instead.

**When you return something from a constructor function it returns that value, and not the instance of the function.**

You see when you execute `new Person(123, "Mahesh")` a new instance of `Person` is created. This is accessible within the constructor function as `this`.

If you don't return anything from your constructor then JavaScript automatically returns `this`. However you're explicitly returning another object.

No wonder `var person` doesn't have `id` and `name` properties (which you only defined on `this`).

In addition `print` doesn't display the `id` and `name` because although you declared them (`var id, name`) you didn't give them any values. Hence they are `undefined`.

This is how I would rewrite your `Person` constructor:

```
function Person(id, name) {
    this.getId = function () {
        return id;
    };

    this.getName = function () {
        return name;
    };

    this.setName = function (new_name) {
        name = new_name;
    };

    this.print = function () {
        document.writeln("Id: " + id + "<br/>Name: " + name);
    };
}
```

I didn't set the `id` and `name` properties on `this` because it makes no sense to include them.

Comment: Using `new` is actually no problem here.

Comment: @Bergi - I agree. The OP is explicitly returning an object anyway. However I believe he wants to create an instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain using the following:

```
// Scope 1
var Person = function (_id,_nm) {
    // Scope 2
    var id, name;    

    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _nm;

    return {
        // Scope 3
        setName: function (nm) {
            name = nm;
        },
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        },
        getId: function () {
            return id;
        },
        print: function () {
            $("#output").append("<p>Id: "+id+"; Name: "+name  + "<p/>");
        }
    }
}
```

The `print` method will return `undefined` because you are referring to the `var id, name;` that is never set in your code.  You set the `_id` and `_name` to the property `id` and `name` but you fail to return the object that you just created.  Instead, you return a dictionary, that references the `name` and `id` variable you created in `Scope 2` that you never set, hence the undefined output in the `print()` call.

Here is what you should have done:

```
var NewPerson = function (_id,_nm) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _nm;  

    this.print = function () {
        $("#output").append("<p>New Person Id: "+this.id+"; Name: "+ this.name  + "<p/>");
    };

    return this;
};

var nperson = new NewPerson(456, "Marcos");
nperson.print();
```

This will output:

```
New Person Id: 456; Name: Marcos
```

In essence, `new` is creating a new object represented by `this`, and you must return `this`  to have a reference to the object created.  In fact, if you do not use the `new` before creating an object, you end up referencing a global instance of `this`.  Try the following:

```
var nperson = new NewPerson(456, "Marcos");
this.name = "Hello";
nperson.print();

var nperson1 = NewPerson(456, "Marcos");
this.name = "Hello";
nperson1.print();
```

You will see that the first output will be as expected:

```
New Person Id: 456; Name: Marcos
```

But the second will pick up the change made to `this.name`:

```
New Person Id: 456; Name: Hello
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcoslin/5vp2R/2/).